# php - check if image has incorrect file extension, then remedy

Tags: php, image

I've built a CMS for a client and he's trying to upload an screenshot image he took with his android tablet. The image is in png format, and uploads fine, but when I try to convert it to jpg with PHP (like I do with all images on the site) and create a thumbnail, the file isn't converted. My conversion code works perfectly on every other image.

When I downloaded the image to my computer and tried to open it with photoshop it said "Could not complete your request because the file-format module cannot parse the file." So I changed the file extension to .jpg and photoshop opened the file perfectly, and it then also uploaded and converted perfectly, generating the correct thumbnail. I'm guessing the file is encoded as a jpg, but somehow the android tablet labeled it as a png? My question is, is there any way in PHP to check the encoding of the image and then change the file extension appropriately?

Comment: [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the inner structure of a file by using [finfo_file()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). This will allow you to retrieve the MIME type of a file. While it's not 100% foolproof, for images, it should work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you do something like the following:

```
$extension = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = end($extension);
if($extension=="gif" && $_FILES['file']['type']=="image/gif") {
//Continue
} else {
//Rename file here
}
```

That should get you started, hopefully you understand what I'm going for.

Comment: this won't work. Browser gets mime type from extension.

Comment: @Ghigo I'm not entirely sure that's correct, when I tested this with my own script, I renamed a GIF to JPG, and it fired the else statement.

Comment: Correct. Extension was not gif, so went to "else" branch.

Comment: @Ghigo In another test I uploaded a JPG disguised as a GIF, and it still went to the else branch.

Comment: You cannot rely on content type. A smart browser could adjust it, but a dummy one won't.

Answer (score 0):

Use php function `getimagesize`. This function will return also image format details.

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
if (is_array($size)) {
  echo 'width: '.$size[0].' height: '.$size[1].' type: '.$size[2];
   // check type as IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_BMP
} else {
  echo 'unknown image format.';
}
```